# Where should "FuelSDK_config.xml" live in my project? Getting "clientId or clientSecret is null" error

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, client-id

I'm getting the following error: "clientId or clientSecret is null: Must be provided in config file or passed when instantiating ET_Client"

I have a "FuelSDK_config.xml" with my clientId and clientSecret. Where should I include this xml file and how is it referenced?

Thank you very much for your time. Please let me know if I am being unclear or if you need anything else from me.

Answer (score 0):

It should need to be in the same location as the DLL, but I would recommend specifying the values when instantiating ET_Client, example code:

```
NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
parameters.Add("clientId", "3bjbc3mg4nbk64z5kzczf89n");
parameters.Add("clientSecret", "ssnGAPvZg6kmm775KPj2Q4Cs");
ET_Client myclient = new ET_Client(parameters);
```